# How do I view the full TCP packet that Apache Kafka produces?

Tags: tcp, apache-kafka

I am using Apache Kafka. I use `KafkaProducer` to produce data and `KafkaConsumer` to consume data. My config data is:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "DemoProducer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

The consumer config is the same. How do I view the whole TCP packet details which are being sent and received by the producers and consumers?

Comment: Haven't seen a built-in tool like that in Kafka. You may need tcpdump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tshark with a Kafka dissector already available.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tshark
sudo tshark -V -i lo -o 'kafka.tcp.port:9092' -d tcp.port=9092,kafka -f 'dst port 9092'
```

More details here [Using the kafka dissector in wireshark/tshark 1.12](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-users/201408.mbox/%3C20140812180358.GA24108@idrathernotsay.com%3E)

Comment: It didn't work for me with a default version of tshark coming from Ubuntu repository. I had to add the following repository first: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wireshark-dev/stable`

Answer (score 2):

After you installed Wireshark, you must go to `Edit->Prefrences` or press `Ctrl + Shift + P`. In the new window open `protocols` tree and find `Kafka` in the list. After selecting `Kafka` you must set the Kafka broker port numbers(It's by default 9092). And Also check `Show length for string and bytes fields in the protocol tree` checkbox as shown in blew image:

[image]

and click ok to dismiss the window. And then you can view all Kafka APIs calls:

[image]