# Kafka Producer should retry three times in case fail

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I want to implement Kafka producer retry logic three times in case of any failure and also i want to test manually whether producer is retrying or not.  Can you suggest me, how to manually test this functionality. In below configuration is added to producer configuration to retry in case of any failure. Thank you.

```
props.put("retries", 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should trust this core functionality of Kafka, but you can track it with capturing the packets of the Producer.

you can use `tcpdump` in order sniff packets on the producer server and check how many time they sent:
`tcpdump -i any port 9092`
I also recommend you to view this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38396574/7804876) about using tshark for capturing Kafka.

If you want to investigate the protocol even deeper you can use WireShark.
Check out this guide about [how to install WireShark on Linux](https://linuxtechlab.com/install-wireshark-linux-centosubuntu/).

Comment: Thank you **Ofek Hod**, for your response. I tried to test retries of kafka producer by reducing request time and also i tried with different timings of kafka producer config parameters. After that it gives time out exception, but kafka producer didn't tried to send request again. So i want to know any way to test this functionality.

Comment: You mean you already sniffed the network and saw that there is only one request? If not, how did you check the number of retries?  About how to get kafka to actually make a second retry (or more), I'll come back with an answer :)

Comment: As per producer config, producer should retry in case of any failure, but it gives time out exception only. i saw these things in logs. I didn't sniffed the network.

Comment: The producer is throwing exception after he reached his max retries (3 in your case), so it does work, just behind the scenes. My "sniffing" approach ment to make sure it behaves how you expect. Maybe the producer does log every retry and I am wrong.. have you tried to run it on DEBUG mode?

Comment: Yes, i run it in DEBUG mode, but it didn't shows any log other than time out exception.

Comment: Which version of Kafka do you use?

Comment: I am using kafka_2.13-2.4.0.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting when it not succeeds?

Comment: I am getting **TimeoutException**, when request.timeout.ms config default time is reduced.

Comment: Anyway, I checked the source code and you should be logged for retries (warn logs). Check out `completeBatch` function in Sender class: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/2.4/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/Sender.java

Comment: Ok **Ofek Hod**, Thank you.

Comment: It seems like TimeoutException is handled with the function `failBatch` (line 391), and when the sender is out of retries it also triggers `failBatch` (line 674), which gives up on the batch without any more retires. So maybe TimeoutException is not what are you looking for in order to trigger more retries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210182/discussion-between-ofek-hod-and-netaji).

Comment: I want to know whether it retries or not in log in case of kafka unavailable or any failure.