# capturing an outstream for analysis

Tags: java-8, apache-kafka-streams

I'm used to crafting ProducerRecord instances and schlepping them off to my cluster using

```
// build up properties
// build KakfaProducer with properties
ProducerRecord<String,String> reccord = new ProducerRecord<String,String>("myTopic","woohoo");
producer.send( reccord);
```

this all depends on having the org.apache.kafka.* packages available.

A different 3rd-party application that we can write custom code for in Java8 and Groovy does NOT have org.apache.kafka.* packages available so must craft messages by-hand.

Is there a way(s) to capture what gets sent over the wire for analysis? Perhaps a ByteArrayOutputStream then loading what gets written to the buffer into a bytearray for viewing. Perhaps javax.interceptors.* could be useful.

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

```
<!--  update 2022-06-26T00:10:10.000Z  -->
```

This is all running on a Windoze 10 box to which I have Admin access but cannot add any software to i.e. wireshark. So I can run pktmon and set a filter for port 9002 which the kafka cluster is running on. I also have a PowerShell panel open running kafka-console-producer where I can manually send messages, and a corresponding PowerShell panel open running kafka-console-consumer where I can see the messages appearing. Between all this plus the Java producer and Java consumer there simply must be a way to capture the serialized data on the wire.

```
<!--  update 2022-06-27T05:20:10.000Z  -->
```

Two of the proffered solutions are spot-on -- except both rely on wireshark, which I mentioned I cannot load. Current approach is to create a ServerSocket aimed at port 9092 and an InputStream and try to bind a listener on the port and stream the bytes to an array for inspection. Fingers crossed.

```
<!--  update 2022-06-30T00:40:10.000Z  -->
```

A variation of this *kinda* worked - I shut down my instance of Kafka and started a simple server on port 9092 that simply printed the stream to console. Sending a message from kafka-console-producer caused this to be printed

```
0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1a 0x0 0x12 0x0 0x2 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x10 0x50 0x61 0x73 0x73 0x70 0x6f 0x72 0x74 0x50 0x72 0x6f 0x64 0x75 0x63 0x65 0x72
```

which works out to

```
64-bit integer == 26 == total number of bytes following
32-bit integer ???
32-bit integer ???
64-bit integer == 16 == number of bytes in following string
PassportProducer
```

but no topic, key, or value turns up. Which leads me to think there's some back-and-forth between source and sink. I've tried attaching my server on the same port as the kafka service but get a "port already in use" errmsg. Can't two apps share a port if one only listens?

Comment: It looks like you're describing an [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/262203) so it's tough to know what solution would fit best. If I take a guess, maybe setting up the [REST Proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html) (or use that as inspiration to create your own proxy) would work, or maybe calling [kcat](https://github.com/edenhill/kcat) from inside Java. Can you take a few steps back and describe at a high level what outcome you want? What restrictions are there in the 3rd party app?

Answer (score 0):

Refer [How do I view the full TCP packet that Apache Kafka produces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352631/how-do-i-view-the-full-tcp-packet-that-apache-kafka-produces)

You call also try using any of the following.

https://aristanetworks.force.com/AristaCommunity/s/article/how-to-capture-timestamped-packets-to-a-kafka-broker

https://wiki.wireshark.org/Kafka